# Combinatorics in Java or pseudo code

Tags: java, permutation, combinatorics

I want to generate a series of numbers in a would-be lottery system. Each series is comprised of 6 numbers. The numbers are chosen from a pool of 50 different numbers. Initially 6 numbers are removed from the pool and these six make the jackpot winning series. Order of numbers doesn’t matter.
Now the ticket series. A series has six numbers and it’s a winning series if it has 3 or more numbers in it which match the numbers in the jackpot one. So, if the jackpot is 1,2,3,4,5,6 for example, a series of 1,2,3,7,8,9 or 1,2,3,4,0,19 can be regarded as a winner.
Now my problem. I want to generate all the ticket series that win (each has exactly six numbers in it and has 3 or more matching numbers in them). Since the order doesn’t matter, I think the mathematical answer is [(6 choose 3) * (44 choose 3)] + [(6 choose 4) * (44 choose 2)] + [(6 choose 5) * (44 choose 1)] + 1. Correct me if I am wrong please. But, I also want to know how to implement that preferably in Java or some pseudo code.
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not to do your job for you. Come back when you have a *specific* question and not a software requirement.

Comment: @SJuan76 This is not part of my job. I am a student preparing for an internship interview. I came across this question. I am not sure how I could be more specific. Could you elaborate please? It's a math problem I am trying to solve. And I asked for Java implementation (preferably) because I am more familiar with that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get better responses and fewer downvotes, first go through the [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), then read the help center, especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then post your question according to these guidelines.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you. I thought I was asking for an algorithm to solve the problem. I did try it on my own first. That's how I came up with my included solution. But when I tried to implement it, I couldn't. Thus, I came here.

Comment: The formula you have found indicates a way for generating those sets. If you find a way of generating "all triples out of six", "all quadruples out of six",... just combine them with "all triples out of 44", etc.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the rules. The idea is not that you try, and once you fail you can come to us. The idea is to come to us with something specific in your implementation that isn't working. If you are not able to produce a basic implementation that produces the combinations, it means you need some tutoring in programming, and this site does not do that, nor does it provide pre-cooked solutions (these fall under "too broad"). You'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think someone wants to post a solution for something they believe to be too simple for you to try on your own first. Please supply what you have tried on your own and someone will be more likely to give you pointers on specific places.

Comment: There are (50 factorial / 44 factorial) total combinations or total tickets that could be sold.  There are (50 factorial / 47 factorial * 4) combinations of winning tickets.  That's 11,441,304,000 total tickets, with 470,400 winning tickets.  I hope you have a lot of paper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Haskell which, since you were interested in Java, probably qualifies as pseudo-code.

```
-- Return a list of tickets drawn from the numbers in nums
-- having length n and at least k numbers in common with jackpot.
winners :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
winners n k jackpot nums = go n k (length jackpot) nums
  where
    -- needed = count of numbers needed to fill a ticket
    -- jneeded = count of jackpot numbers needed for a winner
    -- jleft = count of jackpot numbers left in the list nums
    -- nums = remaining numbers to pick from
    go :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
    go needed jneeded jleft nums
      | needed <= 0                = if jneeded <= 0 then [ [] ] else []
      | jneeded > jleft            = []
    go needed jneeded jleft []     = []
    go needed jneeded jleft (d:ds) = useD ++ dontUseD
        where
          jneeded' = if elem d jackpot then jneeded-1 else jneeded
          jleft'   = if elem d jackpot then jleft-1   else jleft
          useD     = map (d:) $ go (needed-1) jneeded' jleft' ds
          dontUseD = go needed jneeded jleft' ds

example = print $ winners 4 2 [2,5,8] [1..9]
```